# Makefile : How to install a project with a file pkg-config

Tags: c++, makefile, pkg-config

I am trying to make a clean install of my c++ project :

- exports the .h inside an include/ dir
- compile a .dylib (macos) or .so (ubuntu) inside a lib/ dir

Now the question is : **How do I write/export a pkg-config .pc file, with the makefile, that will correspond to my project.** In Mac OS and Linux, so I can just call

```
LDFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --libs my_project) 
CPPFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags my_project)
```

In other makefiles, to get the flags to include.

This is what I done so far (macos):

```
install : $(OBJS)
  mkdir -p $(INSTALL_LIB_DIR)
  $(CXX) -dynamiclib $^ $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(INSTALL_LIB_DIR)/lib$(ENGINE_LIB_NAME).dylib
  mkdir -p include
  cp src/*.h include/
  cp src/*.tpp include/
  mv include $(INSTALL_DIR)
  rm -rf include
  rm -rf lib

uninstall:
  @echo "Removing dir " $(INSTALL_DIR)
  rm -r $(INSTALL_DIR)
```

Thank you very much.
If it can't be done, I will look into doing that with cmake instead...

Comment: Is the question about what to do to get `pkg-config` to work with your project? What file/etc. you need to create for that?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry, if I am not clear enough. I want to add the informations of my project inside pkg-config, so that other people don't have to think about the other dependencies they have to link with my project. I understand I have to create a specific .pkg-config file for that, and I would like to do it directly from the makefile.

Comment: So then yes, you want to know how to get `pkg-config` to know about your project. You need to write a `.pc` file for your project and install it. Run `pkg-config --debug` and you'll see which files it is reading. Look at some of them for the general idea and then look at the [Guide to pkg-config](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html). Also the `pkg-config` man page is useful.

Comment: @EtanReisner But as many have done this before, I expected that tools existed to write those .pc file directly from the makefile, no ?

Comment: They are just text files. There's nothing special about them. And no `make` doesn't do that sort of thing for you. The autotools/etc. might have things that make it easier for you to put the right values in but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ok thank you very much. I have seen this can be done from cmake, and I have to configure my project with cmake anyway so this will wait ;). I will post the response of how I did that with cmake as soon as I finished it ;) Thank you !